# How to get LigHTTPD to run mod_perl code?

Tags: perl, lighttpd, mod-perl

I have a MapToStorageHandler in my mod_perl package, is there anyway to get this to work in LigHTTPD?  I've seen tons of code on running a script, but not anything about Handlers in the chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mod_perl` is an Apache module. You can't run `mod_perl` code on another HTTP server.

Comment: I understand that, but is there a way to do what I need it to do?  Using perl code to map urls to files?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide on how to setup Lighttpd and Perl

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/lighttpd-howto-setup-cgi-bin-access-for-perl-programs.html

Basically, just add this to your config

```
cgi.assign = ( ".pl" => "/usr/bin/perl" )
```

Comment: Handler, not script.  Handlers are in the form of packages .pm